# How to recover Samsung Galaxy Fit using software that works on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, 4.2-jelly-bean, linux, fastboot, samsung-galaxy-fit

I tried to install the new Jelly Bean on my Samsung Galaxy Fit, but it got stuck during installation with an error on `/tmp/slideloadpackage.zip`. Now, my original Android OS lost.

How can I recover my phone using software that works on Ubuntu (12.4)?

I am able to access "download mode". I need to transfer the update file (`BENI_v1.0.ops`) to the device.

Comment: You can do so using the right software and the correct steps. Sorry if this answer doesn't help you -- but it's as precise and detailed as your question. If you need more details, so do we: What exactly happened, where did you get stuck, can you still boot into recovery or at least download mode... Please include at least those basics.

Comment: Yes, I able to access downloading mode and boot mode.

I am looking for right ubuntu based software so I can transfer files(like BENI_v1.0.ops) to devices.

I have copied new android jally bean os in sdcard.
but when i am going to install it, it error: /tmp/slideloadpackage.zip

Comment: I am getting error: /tmp/slideloadpackage.zip may be due to root access permission, but how to resolve it. !!

Comment: Though that's at least *some* additional information (hint: you can edit your question to include more details -- I will do so now with those details you've just provided), it's still not enough. Where did you get that update from? Is it really compatible with your device? What instructions have you been following? Keep in mind that things obvious to you (as you did those steps) are most likely hidden to us, as we didn't sit next to you.